# How can i bind my Angular App with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: angular, azure, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory

I have created an Angular App with just two components, Login and User Details component. Wanted to show the logged in user details only. Whenever I click on login button from application it redirects me to azure-client. Getting below redirection url on browser.  Please suggest/recommend next steps?

[image]

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    UserDetailComponent,
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
          clientId: '************************************', // This is your client ID
          authority: '********************************************', // This is your tenant info
          redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/' // This is your redirect URI
      },
      cache: {
          cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
      },
   }),
  ],
  providers: [UserService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
  }],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserDetailComponent } from './user-detail/user-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'userDetail', component: UserDetailComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Login method that will be called on click of login button of custom Ui

```
login(username, password) : Observable<any> {

    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers = headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.append('Content-type', 'text/html');
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    
     return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8082/check', { username, password }, {headers})
        .pipe(map(user => {
               return user;
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Did you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-angular ?

Comment: Yes, i have followed these steps and configured my application accordingly.

Comment: please post your login code, app.module.ts and app-routing.module.ts

Comment: @corradolab added all the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To login to Azure using MsalModule you must call

```
msalService.loginPopup();
```

or

```
 msalService.loginRedirect();
```

the former being the suggested one.

See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts